# creating multiple children using appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am creating a simple todo app.

When I add a todo and list them, I want to show `delete` and `change status` button with every todo,

But only one button appears,

[image]

See, first button(delete button) is very tiny and doesn't even function. But it works perfectly when I add only 1 button.

Here is the js for adding the list item and button,

```
var view = {
  displaytodos: function(){
  var todoul = document.querySelector('ul');
  todoul.innerHTML = '';
  for (var i=0;i < todolist.todos.length;i++){
    var newli = document.createElement('li');
    newli.setAttribute('class','text-success');
    var todotextwithstatus = '';
    if (todolist.todos[i].completed === true){
      todotextwithstatus = '(X) - ' + todolist.todos[i].todotext + ' --> ';
    }
    else{
      todotextwithstatus = '( ) - ' + todolist.todos[i].todotext + ' --> ';
    }

    newli.id = i;
    newli.textContent = todotextwithstatus;
    delbtn = this.createdeletebutton();
    statusbtn = this.createstatusbutton();
    newli.appendChild(statusbtn);
    newli.appendChild(delbtn);
    todoul.appendChild(newli);
  }
},
createdeletebutton: function(){
  var delbtn = document.createElement('button');
  delbtn.textContent = 'Delete';
  delbtn.className = 'DeleteElement';
  return delbtn;
},
createstatusbutton: function(){
  var statusbtn = document.createElement('button');
  delbtn.textContent = 'Change Status';
  delbtn.className = 'changestatusbutton';
  return statusbtn;
},
```

This is the html,

```
<div class='col-xs-4'>
  <h3>Your todos will appear here.</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>You have not added any todos yet.</li>
  </ul>
  <button onclick='handlers.toggle_all()'>Change status of all Todos</button>
</div>
```

What is the solution for this? Why is this happening?

Comment: In `createstatusbutton` you're assigning to `delbtn` properties instead of `statusbtn` properties.

Comment: This should be making a tiny, empty status button, and the delete button should be normal. I don't understand why you're getting the opposite.

Comment: yeah me too, I dont understand. Anyway, any other way to create 2 buttons like this?

Comment: Your way is fine. Just fix the typo.

Comment: looks like createdeletebutton and createstatusbutton are outside the view object.